# WooCommerce: Display specific attribute of selected variation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woocommerce-theming

I want to display a specific attribute of my product based on the selected variation of the product. It should show below the price on the product page. And it should update when I change the variation.

I tried to display it with this code:

```
$product = wc_get_product();
echo $product->get_attribute( 'pa_traffic' );
```

It works fine but shows all the attribute/variations of the product. Is there any way to show it only if a variation is selected and show only the attribute of the variation?

Comment: where you want to show that information? Frontend Variable Product? Can you please edit your question with use case where and why you want to list that information? Do you know the variation id? If so you can simply pass the variation id to the `wc_get_product($variation_id);` and get the `$product->get_variation_attributes();` or use the following function [wc_get_formatted_variation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_formatted_variation.html)

Comment: I changed the question

Comment: Yes this is doable, but that can be achieved using js/ajax you need to first fetch the variation trigger selection(js) and upon trigger you will get associated variation id and that can be passed via ajax to fetch your desired result.